# Count the number of UNIQUE values in a TEXT field

Tags: views, entities

I'm creating a View to count the total number of unique values for a text field. This text field has a limit of one during input, so there are no additional values to check. I tried the aggregate and distinct options in the advanced tab, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

I picked count distinct, but it still shows the duplicates as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the next thing:

Enable `distinct` option in query settings. Then in field's aggregation settings choose `count DISTINCT` option(not just `count`!).

Hope it'll help. This worked for me.

Comment: doesnt work....

Answer (score 0):

The drupal zealots will hate me for this for using php in the ui. I used php views and did a custom sql query to output the number of unique values for a field. My field was called campaign.

```
<?php 
$campaign_query = db_query('select count(distinct(field_campaign_value)) from field_data_field_campaign');
$campaign_total = $camp_query->fetchAll();

$ctotal = $campaign_total[0]->{'count(distinct(field_campaign_value))'};

echo '<div class="views-php-totals">'. $ctotal .' Campaigns</div>';
?>
```

The "proper" drupal way to do it is the create a new module and inject that code into the views header. But if your just a solo dev or a small team, doing my way would be the quickest.